# VS Code: "Flow is type checking"... Forever

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, flowtype

I'm running VS Code 1.28.2 on Windows 7 Pro.

I have an existing project that I'm trying to add Flow to. This project already has many installed `dependencies` and `devDependencies`.

I have...

- Installed `flow-bin` (`0.83.0`).
- Installed the [Flow Language Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=flowtype.flow-for-vscode) VS Code extension.
- Created a `.flowconfig` file.
- Restarted VS Code

The first code I'm trying to add types to looks like this (an extract):

```
// @flow
async function actionAttributesFilteredToShop (stateData: {}, { tables, products }: {}): Promise<any> {
  return {}
}
```

Now, not much is happening in terms of type checking my code, and I think it's because Flow is running and possibly trying to type check all my dependencies, which right now is about 17,000 files in `node_modules`.

I see this in the bottom left-hand corner in VS Code (the `\` is a loading spinner):

[image: Flow is type checking]

Never-ending "Flow is type checking"...

What is it type checking!? Is there a way to see the files that are currently being type checked..?

How long should it take..?